# async await not woring in Dreamfactory node.js scripts

Tags: node.js, dreamfactory

```
1. const getAsset = async (assetName) => {
2.    const url = `/database/_table/asset?filter=(name=${assetName})`;
3.    return await df.get(url);
4. }
```

Line 1: Expected '(' and instead saw '{'
Line 2: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'const' (A reserved keyword)

no matter how I use I'm getting all sorts of errors

```
1. async function getAsset(assetName) {
2.    const url = `/database/_table/asset?filter=(name=${assetName})`;
3.    return await df.get(url);
4. }
```

As far as I know the node.js version in Dreamfactory is 8.11.4

Comment: shouldn't you be using  '?' instead of '&' in your url?

Comment: i've removed some code when i was posting the question, yes i'm using it, thank you